# Connect with FIREBASE manually: Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.10

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

When I am trying to connect my project with FIREBASE manually, this error occurs

```
 A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'. > Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.10:. Required by: project : * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 2s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have followed the tutorials, but in my case, it throws an error message. Please suggest to me where I am making a mistake.